# "お調べいただいた上、" vs. "お調べいただき、..."

Tags: translation, set-phrases

What is the difference in meaning between:

> (1) お調べいただいた**上{うえ}**、注文通りの品をお送り下さいますよう、お願いします。
>   (2) お調べ**いただき**、注文通りの品を送り下さいますよう、お願いします。

I understand #2.

> (2) Upon your looking into the matter, please send me the stuff I ordered.

I can't figure-out how to voice "*いただいた上、*" in English in my head. I want a strict translation, not a paraphrase. Nothing is clicking for me, but this is my best try:

> (1) Please look into the matter, and then based on what (I expect) you to find, send me the stuff I ordered.

Also, I am seriously hoping that "*で*" was dropped off the end of "いただいた上**で**、".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### X as a prerequisite for Y:

X is what must be done before Y.

> X いただいた上、Y してください。
>
> After (and only after) doing X, do Y.

---

### X and or then Y:

The order of completing X and Y is not strictly emphasized.

> X いただき、Y してください。
>
> Do X, and do Y.

---

See how (1) is asking a little more explicitly that you actually read the document before signing:

> 1. お読みいただいた上、こちらにご署名{しょめい}ください。
>
> After reading (the document), sign your name here.
>
> 2. お読みいただき、こちらにご署名{しょめい}ください。
>
> Read (the document), and sign your name here.

It would be weird to say (1) when the order doesn't matter:

> 1. フォークはこちらに置{お}いていただいた上、スプーンはこちらに置{お}いてください。
>
> After putting the forks here, put the spoons here.
>
> 2. フォークはこちらに置{お}いていただき、スプーンはこちらに置{お}いてください。
>
> Put the forks here, and put the spoons here.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. The "で" has been dropped off the end of "いただいた上で、".

Check this page (http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=uede) for other examples, including a note lower down that this can be dropped.

Comment: yes. I know the "上で" grammar. But, it seems #1 is forced in this scenario. #2 is slick, fast, "A-いただき、B-下さいますように、お願い". In #1, when I hit "いただいた上で、" my world stops. "いただいた上で、" can have so much meaning. "上で" is an abstract way to connect clauses. And, I don't feel the abstractness. Now, I blow by that phrase and take an educated guess. I need to do better than this on JLPT...