# Understanding としたうえで

Tags: grammar

> 民事訴訟法の改正案では、現在は書面に限られている裁判所への訴状や準備書面の提出について、オンラインでの手続きを可能にする**としたうえで**、弁護士などの代理人には、オンラインでの提出を義務づけるとしています。

How should I understand the bold としたうえで? Does it mean the same as としたら? And にする already means "make A B", why is とする used there, which also means "make A B"?

Like "If handling procedures online is made possible"?

Comment: Related: [“お調べいただいた上、" vs. "お調べいただき、…”](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27789/43676)

Answer (score 1):

した上で isn't the same as したら.

Not sure I'm finding the right words but it implies sequential actions that you plan on doing.

> オンラインでの手続きを可能にするとしたら

Would be "If we make the application submittable online..."

while

> オンラインでの手続きを可能にするとしたうえで

is rather "We're gonna make the application submittable online and **on top of that**..."

Comment: This is 上**で** not 上**に**

Comment: I vote for oldergod. "としたうえで" can be rephrased as "とし、そのうえで" in this case. Argumentative phrase frequently seen in legal contexts.